# Localization in windows application using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nvda

I am working on a windows application that needs to localize to the Spanish language . Once localization is done while testing the tool screen reader the contents are available in Spanish visually but when we check them with the screen reader the contents are read out by the screen reader in English(default language). so are there any configuration settings that need to be done or how to solve this issue can anyone suggest me any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I have completely implemented the localization

Comment: Are you changing language by system or by application?

Comment: Have you set the AccessibleName and AccessibleRole properties of the UI controls? You can use the [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility-tools-docs/) tool to find problems. The [tool samples for WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility-tools-docs/items/winforms/list_name) show how to fix several problems. In some cases, eg ListBox and ListView, you need to localize the `AccessibleName` property

Comment: The screen reader is probably using the System locale as the default language. If it provides a configurable auto-switch feature, you need to check the manual to determine what conditions this feature relies upon (and how to enable it). Could be based on Accessibility or auto-detection

Comment: @ChrisBD I am changing the language by application

Comment: Try changing the system language and see what happens - I suspect that @Jimi is correct.